# Updating older code from OS X 10.6 to 10.7

Tags: macos, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to update **ODBCQueryTool** so it builds under 10.7. It was originally targeted against  10.6, which is not directly supported in newer versions of Xcode. For now a working build would be fine, but ideally I'd like to make a version that builds and runs on 10.5 or newer.

So to start I downloaded and installed the 10.6 SDK. A number of problems disappeared at that point, but I got a series of these:

**ld: warning**:
`directory not found for option` `'-F/Users/maury/Develop/odbckit/ODBCQueryTool/../ODBCKit/build/Release`'

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableOrderedSet", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libarclite_macosx.a(arclite.o)
```

I can't find anything useful in Google. I was under the impression that ARC was part of 10.7 and newer, so it's not clear why I get these at all.

Comment: Try this: in build settings set "Implicitly link Objective-C Runtime Support" to NO.

Comment: Thank you! That is somewhat obscure...

Comment: @Chris You should make an answer of that... I was slowly going crazy thanks!

Comment: @Chris that should definitely be an answer, thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just making this an answer based on Chris's post:

In build settings set "Implicitly link Objective-C Runtime Support" to NO.